# What to do to be able to switch from SATA mode AHIC -> RAID RST in Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, raid, sata, intel-rst

I have the following MOBO https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_IV_EXTREME/ and the hardware configuration:

1. Main SSD disk #1 with Ubuntu 18.04 x64 on 6G SATA connector.
2. Main SSD disk #2 with Windows 7 Pro x64 on 6G SATA connector.
3. I use grub bootloader to do dual booting.
4. Four additional identical disks connected to the 3G SATA connectors.

I'd like to setup a RAID-10 for the four identical disks so I switch the BIOS from `SATA mode AHIC -> RAID (RST)`. This triggers the Intel RAID utility that let's me configure the RAID-10 np.

However, the result is that Windows 7 crashes and won't boot anymore, the switch from `AHIC -> RAID (RST)` provokes this. I realize it doesn't have the drivers installed but it won't let me install the drivers beforehand because at that time the drivers don't find the hardware ... like the chicken and the egg problem ... lovely Windows. I have tried installing these drivers before and during the Windows crash without success: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26759/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-User-Interface-and-Driver?product=55005

Ubuntu 18.04 boots no problem but then it still "sees" four different drives and `GParted` even complains and asks to fix the GPT partitions of those drives trashing the Intel rapid storage RAID-10 setup.

Can anyone advice what to do 1) for Windows 7 and 2) for Ubuntu 18.04 to put these nice four drives to work as a hardware RAID-10 and make good use of them?

Is there another solution e.g. building a software RAID-10 e.g. from Ubuntu that Windows will also recognize?

Comment: AFAIK Intel RST is not yet supported in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to BIOS
2. Change the mode of hard drives on AHCI (so that you can boot Windows).
3. Load Windows.
4. Run the registry editor, to do this, open the "Start" and enter `regedit`.
5. Open the registry branch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStorV`.
6. We look for the parameter `REG_DWORD` called `Start` and change its value from "3" to "0".
7. Open the registry branch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor`.
8. We look for the parameter `REG_DWORD` called `Start` and change its value from "0" to "3".
9. Close the registry editor and restart the computer.
10. Go to the BIOS and change the mode of hard drives from AHCI to RAID.
11. Load the Windows. In my case, the loading Windows without problems, the only problem is the failed activation of Windows.

still found it - https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on but did not try.