# Dual Booting Windows 10 & Ubuntu on ASUS FX504

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

I'm having trouble figuring out if Ubuntu is attempting to install on the right drive.

Basically, this is a new laptop. It came with Windows 10 already installed and I don't want to change that, so I created a partition on disk so I can dual boot with Ubuntu.

I read and watched a few hot-to blogs/videos, but none seem to arrive  at the screen I do. What happens is:

1. I get into the BIOS and select the USB that has the Linux distribution I want to boot with.
2. I press 'e' and enter the command 'nouveau.modest=0' after the 'quick splash' mention, or somesuch.
3. It brings me to the Ubuntu installation wizard. I select my language and keyboard preference, then the Minimalist installation (I don't want any clutter of any kind as this boot serves a specific purpose).
4. This is where my confusion begins. It asks me where I want to install the Ubuntu. There's what seems to be a list (with a +, - and 'Change' option just below) that's empty. When I press on one of those options, the wizard window simply closes. Furthermore, below that list (and its options), I see a folder 'dev/sda' in a drop-menu. There's no other option in that drop-menu.

I'm not sure whether I should just leave all that as is and continue with the installation. I'm not keen on clicking that 'Install Now' option as I don't want to screw with my Windows 10 install.

Anybody faced this before and has some advice?

Comment: **Everybody** with new system with the typical drive settings being other than AHCI have faced the same problem. You need to first install AHCI drivers in Windows then change the mode to AHCI. Now all your drives will be detected.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thank you. Do you know where I could find that driver? I looked around, but see nothing explicit and easy. I'm a bit new about hardware and system.

https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX504/HelpDesk_Download/

That website seems close to what I need, but nothing mentions AHCI driver.

Comment: This method from a recent answer should work: https://superuser.com/a/1446581/931000

Comment: It seems like a mighty fine solution, except when I activate AHCI directly in my BIOS, I simply can't get to Windows startup. Tried before.

Comment: You need to first enable the mode AHCI in Windows. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/how-to-enable-ahci-for-ssd-in-windows-10/18ee0b43-47a9-4344-b0c8-1e8546be2c82

Comment: I tried a bunch of things and nothing worked. Too complicated for my taste and my current need, so I'll leave this thread open, but I found another solution. I'm using virtual machines. Not elegant, but it answers my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions as in [Installing Ubuntu (dual boot) on a Dell Precision which already runs Windows 10](https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/installing-ubuntu-dual-boot-on-a-dell-precision-which-already-runs-windows-10/), first option **Change the BIOS SATA operation mode from RAID to AHCI** did it for me:

1. Windows Disk Management tool: shrink main partition to make space for Ubuntu.
2. Open command prompt as admin, enter bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal. This will tell Win10 to load AHCI driver by next boot. Reboot.
3. During reboot enter BIOS setup via F2 or F12.
4. Change SATA Operation mode from RAID On to AHCI.
5. Save the changes and exit BIOS. The system will reboot and should automatically boot into Windows 10 safe-mode. Windows should now automatically detect the AHCI hardware setting and add the appropriate drivers to the windows boot loader.
6. Once in Windows safe-mode, open a command prompt as administrator again.
7. Enter 'bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot'.
8. Reboot again and Windows will now automatically start with the AHCI drivers enabled.

Now you are ready to install Ubuntu again and the installer should be able to detect your AHCI hardware and drive.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Links can change, become out of date or disappear altogether; can you [edit] your answer and include the relevant info in it?